# Create object files in specific directory through Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

While this works perfectly :

```
object.o:   $(SRCDIR)object.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEDIR) $<
    mv object.o $(OBJDIR)
```

The goal is to create .o file inside a directory automatically while creating it. ie. not like first create and then move.

I did this :

```
$(OBJDIR)/object.o: $(SRCDIR)object.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEDIR) $<
```

This one outputs : `make: *** No rule to make target 'object.o', needed by 'all'.  Stop.`

Any direction, how to achieve that?

Comment: Does `SRCDIR` contains the `/` ? Since `OBJDIR` don't seems like it got it, since you add it at the end.

Comment: @kaldoran yes 
SRCDIR:=src/

Comment: You need to post your makefile, not just bits.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Thanks for your concern. Solved it. and written the solution here in Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

```
object.o:   $(SRCDIR)object.c
    $(CC) -c -o $(OBJDIR)/object.o $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEDIR) $^
```

Comment: That is a recipe that will never create its target. It is the wrong solution. It solves the problem you know about by creating others you have yet to discover.

Comment: @MikeKinghan can you please elaborate ? I needed to create .o files only. I had created the target later on. linking all the .o files which is not given in the snippet of my Makefile.

Comment: @MikeKinghan ie. 
executable: $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(OBJ))
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@ $^
Hope this clarifies

Comment: @MikeKinghan also the heading is "Create object files in specific directory through Makefile" So the problem I faced was to build .o files into a specific directory only. As per SO guidelines I needed to be specific to problem. Hence thought of posting only the problem area. However as you suggested, I will think about it for more elaborate problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$(OBJS) = $(patsubst $(SRCS),$(SRCDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

$(OBJS) : $(SRCDIR)/%.o : $(OBJDIR)/%.c
    @echo "$< => $@"
    @$(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEDIR) $<
```

This is a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) which says to build your objects using a specific pattern.   Notice that I assume you moved the trailing `/` out of `$(SRCDIR)` (as it's cleaner that way).

Comment: Also, you may want to look up order only dependencies for creating `$(OBJDIR)` as well

Comment: yup, I had moved out / and also used static pattern rule later on. Thanks for the concern though.